# Google app engine JDO data store design using inheritance

Tags: google-app-engine, inheritance, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am using subtable inheritance strategy to design my data store using JDO for my application hosted in google app engine. There are three types of users that can logs into my app.
these are the classes that I designed for this purpose 1) User(Abstract)
2)UserType1 extends User 3) UserType2 extends User 4) UserType3 extends User. Now the problem is every time I want to find an user based on the userId I have to check each entity kind separatly. It will become more problem when the user types increases. Please help how to design the model classes in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for JDO2's [superclass-table](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/inheritance.html#superclasstable) inheritance technique. it works similar to the python app engine [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html) class.

unfortunately, app engine [doesn't support superclass-table](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Inheritance) right now. instead, consider consolidating all of the different class's fields into a single User class with a type enum.